# Covert home pc to web server steps

Tags: iis, webserver

I want to convert my home pc to a web server. Already IIS8 has been installed. The sample page has been published on default web site. In windows firewall the port 80 has been opened. I have access to this page through different computers that connect to the same ADSL router. However, when I try to connect to the page from another ISP, I get the error of 'web page not find'. Because I don't have static IP now, I find IP of the server from http://www.whatismyip.com/. I wonder if anybody help my to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround it to use no-ip
http://www.noip.com/
this would give you static IP.
From this point is just normal domain setup.

Comment: Thanks. But I couldn't connect to server. Shall I configure my ADSL router or not?

Comment: Are you talking about port forwarding?

Comment: When I test the IP of whatismyip.com in server computer, the page redirect to ADSL router but when I use IP from IPConfig it works. How can I apply port forwarding.

Comment: Your router must have configuration page like: 192.168.0.1 depends on router